# How to enable guifg and guibg in vim

Tags: vim

As the title says, I want to know how can I enable the `guifg` and `guibg` in vim colorschemes. I already wrote in my vimrc `set t_Co=256`, but it enables only `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` for 256 colors.

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and I'm using `gnome-terminal` (but I tried with `terminator terminal` and also doesn't work)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using a terminal, but want gui colors...? `guifg` and `guibg` are for gvim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`guifg` and `guibg` are always only used by gvim, and `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` are what  vim uses in terminals.

You can find vim plugins that will convert 'on the fly' gui colors to the closest terminal approximations (CSApprox, ColorSupport), or you can use a tool like [Vim-toCterm](http://shawncplus.github.io/Vim-toCterm/) to convert a gui color scheme into terminal one time and then use the new scheme.